# Recommendation of Java or JVM based web app framework

Tags: java, web-applications, jvm

I've been given an assignment to create a visual component for a software competition. The only solid requirements I have are that
1. It needs to visualize data given through ActiveMQ
2. The information needs to be organized and visually appealing (information is presented as charts and graphs, and some nice UI elements are desireable, like tabs, accordion menus etc.)

At first, SmartGWT seemed like a good choice, but it seems that I cannot connect it to any messaging service before upgrading to a paid license, for which I do not have the funds.

Considering the fact that the requirements haven't yet been clearly stated and will be redefined probably in the near future, I cannot waste anymore time studying new technologies only to find out that I cannot use them for my needs. I'm considering something as close to Java (or JVM) as possible, as the software competition is Java based.

So, what framework would you recommend for me and why?

Grateful in advance!

Comment: "but it seems that I cannot connect it to any messaging service before upgrading to a paid license" - where did you get this information?

Comment: @darioo SmartGWT forums, along with their feature comparison chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring MVC ala the [Spring framework](http://www.springsource.org/about).

It works in conjunction with [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html) which meets your initial request. In addition the level of separation via the MVC pattern it provides is very nice as well as the ability to plug-in 3rd party components as needed.

Here is an [article](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Why-Use-the-Spring-Framework-.id-130098.html) stating reasons to make use of Spring. You can ignore the J2EE stuff unless it is applicable to you; however note the Dependency Injection, Inversion of Control, and Aspect programming sections.